# Difference between var array and let array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, var, let

I'm studying arrays in Swift and in my book first they write:

```
let numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

but then write:

```
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I know that `let` denotes *constants* and `var` refers to *variables*, but practically what changes from an array declared as constant and an array declared as variable?

Comment: @Rob how is the link a duplicate? it talks about scope of var/let in javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since arrays in swift are `structs` declaring an array with `let` not only prevents you from assigning a new value to it but also prevents you from changing its contents

so for example:

```
    let arr = [0, 1, 2]
    arr[0] = 10 //will not compile
    arr = [] //will not compile
```

Comment: Thank you, all answers are good and useful but in my opinion yours is more complete. Solved!

Answer (score 2):

The array declared as constant is immutable.

Its size and contents cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

you can not change/add/remove elements of array when it is declared with `let`.
if you want make any changes with an array, you need to declare with `var`.